# Exception on setting background color

Tags: android, exception, resources

I have a menu that should be with white background and black text but intermittently I get exceptions like:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff
```

Obviously that is the set background colour method, here is a code snippet:

```
final View view = f.createView( name, null, attrs );  
// sets the background color   
view.setBackgroundResource(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Resource color's white](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#white).

```
view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white)
```

or set background color instead of resource

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
```

Comment: Vote up for a different, more "Androidish" approach.

Comment: Thanks that was really lame mistake. +1 to your answer really like the `android.R.color.white` approach

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong method for setting the color.

The `setBackgroundResource` method sets the background using a drawable, which you can get using `activity.getResources().getDrawable(ID)`.

But in your case, you need just to set the color, so simply use the method `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)`.

Answer (score 1):

The color is no ressouce use this code:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a background resource, not a background color. Use the setBackgroundColor method, not setBackgroundResource